# Printing unexpanded recursive variables in gnu make

Tags: gnu-make

Is there a way to print the unexpanded definition of a recursive variable?  I have a complicated build system, and a user can set some values.  I'd like to echo the user definition to another file, for later use.

For example,

```
externals = $(HOME)/externals

all:
    echo $(externals)
```

doesn't work, because it echos using the current definition of HOME.  I'd like it to echo
the literal string `$(HOME)/externals` without expanding `$(HOME)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`value` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Value-Function) is probably what you want here.

> 8.8 The value Function
>
> The value function provides a way for you to use the value of a variable without having it expanded. Please note that this does not undo expansions which have already occurred; for example if you create a simply expanded variable its value is expanded during the definition; in that case the value function will return the same result as using the variable directly.
>
> The syntax of the value function is:
>
> ```
>     $(value variable)
> ```
>
> Note that variable is the name of a variable, not a reference to that variable. Therefore you would not normally use a ‘$’ or parentheses when writing it. (You can, however, use a variable reference in the name if you want the name not to be a constant.)
>
> The result of this function is a string containing the value of variable, without any expansion occurring. For example, in this makefile:
>
> ```
>     FOO = $PATH
>
>     all:
>             @echo $(FOO)
>             @echo $(value FOO)
> ```
>
> The first output line would be ATH, since the “$P” would be expanded as a make variable, while the second output line would be the current value of your $PATH environment variable, since the value function avoided the expansion.
>
> The value function is most often used in conjunction with the eval function (see Eval Function).

Though in addition to this you are going to need to use single quotes on that `echo` line or the shell will expand things on you.

```
$ cat Makefile
externals = $(HOME)/externals

all:
        echo $(externals)

allv:
        echo $(value externals)

allvq:
        echo '$(value externals)'
$ make all
echo /home/user/externals
/home/user/externals
$ make allv
echo $(HOME)/externals
/bin/sh: HOME: command not found
/externals
$ make allvq
echo '$(HOME)/externals'
$(HOME)/externals
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like what I want.  Unfortunately, I'm using a really old make (version 3.79.1), and that doesn't appear to be supported; I think it was added in 3.80.  I guess I need to upgrade...